# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tabpy'

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, tabpy

So I did try
`!pip install tabpy` in my Notebook
and it worked and installed all the packages and whatnot.

But in the very next cell, when I tried to run
`import tabpy`, it throws the error
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tabpy'`

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: make sure that the new cell is running the same python on which you installed the tabpy package

Comment: Yea like in the same jupyter notebook on 1 cell I did the pip install and the one after that  I tried importing the module and got the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to import a metadata supplementary package